# Hive replacing a value with null value in hive

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have a hive table where instead of NULL, it represents null record as string with value 'N/A',
Is there any query that will convert that 'N/A' into NULL value datatype in hive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `if` or `case when` or `decode` like below -

```
select 
case when mycol='N/A' then NULL else mycol end as mycol,
if(mycol='N/A', NULL,mycol) as mycol_if
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

The "CASE WHEN" syntax may be helpful.
Create hive table and import data.

```
hive> create table mytable(
    name string,
    mycol string
 )

 row format delimited fields terminated by "\t";
 
 hive> load data local inpath '/opt/tempdata/mytable.txt' into table mytable;
```

sql syntax:

```
 hive> select 
 name,
 case mycol when 'N/A' then NULL else mycol end as mycol
 from mytable
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: appreciate it, it worked for me.